# Swapping declared set dates for last 7 days

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a pre-established SQL script that requires you to set and declare a start and end date:

```
Declare @StartDate DateTime
Declare @EndDate DateTime

Set @StartDate = '07/8/2018'
Set @EndDate = '07/22/2018'

Declare @TESTTrx Table (
BusinessDate DateTime,
StartTime DateTime,
LastItemTime DateTime,
EndTime DateTime,
DevNum Int,
TrxNum Int,
```

A bit further in the script, utilizing the same declarations:

```
Where H.business_date between @StartDate and @EndDate
```

I want to avoid this hassle in an attempt to automate the process entirely. Instead, I'm looking to see how I can declare the start and end date via the past 7 days. Something similar to this, but I'm struggling on figuring out how to incorporate it and to avoid using the manual set start and end dates:

```
WHERE business_date > DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) ;
```

Thanks in advance if anyone has a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
Declare @StartDate DateTime;
Declare @EndDate DateTime;

Set @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY, -7, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()));
Set @EndDate = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE());
```

Comment: Or swap around the `set`s and do `set @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY, -7, @EndDate)` which cures a very tiny race condition. But that's just me being pedantic

Comment: @Charlieface - I'll take note of that as well, thanks!